# Facing Error in running ripple emulator (Chrome extension) for app testing?

Tags: blackberry, google-chrome-extension, ripple

When i just enable a html file from my pc to emulate.It just shows :--

"Looks like what we have here is a failure to... emulate

You're seeing this window because it looks like the zombie apocalypse has started.

"It says Hit or fire" ""

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ABj4.png

It is working few days for me..But now i started opening it i got an error. My Ram is 2Gb and supports full requirements..
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

That message means Ripple is waiting for *something* to finish, and has decided to show a warning rather than hanging.  You can CTRL+I to open web inspector and see if there are any console messages that help explain what failed.

You can hit the FIRE button to clear all cached settings. This will reset Ripple to its initial state (Ripple stores all user settings in localStorage - hitting the FIRE button clears this localStorage data). If a cached setting was the reason for the "red screen of death", then you will see the black "welcome to Ripple" screen after hitting the FIRE button.

Otherwise, I'd suggest disabling and re-enabling Ripple.

Finally as a last resort, make sure to update to the latest version of Ripple using the *.crx file available here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/

Comment: Update: I've been seeing this error when using Chrome in incognito mode. Ripple should support incognito mode, but a fresh install may not support it correctly.  You may need to enable certain security / storage options in order to get past this screen (suggest using Ripple using normal Chrome and not Incognito mode Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access something in your local file system i found the problem

https://github.com/blackberry/Ripple-UI/issues/565

> since you're running in the file:/// scheme, you need to get around
>   the browser's security a little bit. Do the following:
>
> in chrome://chrome/extensions/ make sure the "Allow access to file URLs" is checked for Ripple (might have to go into developer mode to do that, check box on the top right of the page)
>
> quit chrome and restart it with --allow-file-access-from-files flag

doing this resolved the problem for me.
you can check with this page [github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/HelloWorld](http://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/HelloWorld)